# Unity XR.Settings.LoadDeviceByName() not loading device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have tried to use XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName() but it never work. I have already check if the parameter device name is same as the current device name but nothing changes. Also, I have added the None in the sdk list

The XRSettings.loadedDeviceName is cardboard when initiating.

```
IEnumerator testThis() {
  if (string.Compare(XRSettings.loadedDeviceName, "", true) != 0) {
    XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("none");
    some_text.text = XRSettings.loadedDeviceName;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    XRSettings.enabled = true;
    some_text.text = "Device name " + XRSettings.loadedDeviceName;
    }
        
  }
 
  IEnumerator temp() {
    some_text.text = "Device name " + XRSettings.loadedDeviceName;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
    StartCoroutine(testThis());
 }
```

No matter how I detect, the device name is still cardboard.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName.html

What I have done:

1. Make None as one of the Virtual Reality SDKs
2. Use XR-Plugin Management
   2.1 Disable Virtual Reality Supported
   2.2 Convert camera to XR-Rig
   2.3 Use the code about turning VR off in XR-Plugin Management
   2.4 Remarks: all the procedure in step 2 is work in iOS build but fail in android build.
   2.5 https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.management@4.0/manual/index.html
3. Tried XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("none"); XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName(""); XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("None");

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that ''none'' is first in your VR SDK's, Then Cardboard.
2. I see a problem with your compare, there is no value

   if (string.Compare(XRSettings.loadedDeviceName, "", true) != 0) {

If I understand correctly what you want to do, this code down here will receive a device name and will trigger the LoadDevice couroutine with this name.

```
    public void VerifyDeviceName(string newDeviceName)
{
    if (newDeviceName == "none")
    {
        Debug.Log("Will load none device");
        StartCoroutine(LoadDevice(newDeviceName));

    }
    if (newDeviceName == "cardboard")
    {
        Debug.Log("Will load cardboard device");
        StartCoroutine(LoadDevice(newDeviceName));
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Can't find device with name " + newDeviceName);
    }

}

IEnumerator LoadDevice(string newDeviceName)
{
    XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName(newDeviceName);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
    XRSettings.enabled = true;
    Debug.Log("Loaded " + newDeviceName);
}
```

Note; This will obviously not work in editor you wil get a message saying you cannot trigger on/off vr in editor mode.

Comment: I don't think it works, since the problem of mine is the LoadDeviceByName() function doesn't work. I have tried the following code and I keep track on the LoadedDeviceByName in Android phone but that device name is always the same as the name when start. With the use of above code, it is always none.

Comment: To simplify, this code will show "Will load cardboard device" and "Loaded none" in Debug Log if I change Debug.Log("Loaded " + newDeviceName) to Debug.Log("Loaded " + XRSettings.LoadedDeviceName)

Answer (score 0):

I just got through this by brute forcing it. The secret is not to Load device by name. If your trying to load "none" you should just initialize and deinitialize your XR loader.

1. Disable "Initialize XR on Startup" in Project Settings -> XR Plugin Management
2. In the code use these two methods

   IEnumerator StartXR(){
   yield return XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.InitializeLoader();
   if(XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.activeLoader == null){
   Debug.Log("initialization FAILED");
   }
   else{
   XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.activeLoader.Start();
   }
   }
   void StopXR(){
   XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.activeLoader.Stop();
   XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.activeLoader.Deinitialize();
   }
   (Sorry I am terrable at code snippits! I'm new to answering)
   Then call these as you need them. It should turn on and turn off XR in your project